# Hyperbolic function inequality: $ \sinh(x) > \frac12 {\Large(} \frac {\cosh(x)}{\cosh(x-a)} {\Large)}^{x/a} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

Let $a = \frac12 \ln (2)$. Show that, for $x\ge 0.6$,

$$
\sinh(x) - \frac12 {\Large(} \frac {\cosh(x)}{\cosh(x-a)} {\Large)}^{x/a} > 0
$$

The LHS has a maximum at $x \simeq 1.72$ and is approaching zero for larger $x$. However, I find no clue how to show this, since also calculus methods give no closed results.

I also conjecture that this relation holds for other $a$ and for  $x\ge x_0$, where $x_0$ will depend on $a$. See my edit in RiverLi's answer which shows that this is actually true for all $a>0$, and which shows $x_0(a)$.

Comment: What is the origin of this problem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie After a number of twists it recurs to some problem with Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Maybe you can use numeric method to show that there this is true in $[a, 40a]$ using something like [this](https://juliaintervals.github.io/IntervalRootFinding.jl/latest/). Though you would still need an lower bound for the expression on $[40a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitution $x = \ln t$ (see @ablmf's answer), 
it suffices to prove that for all $t \ge \mathrm{e}^{3/5} \approx 1.8221$,
$$\ln\Big(1 - \frac{1}{t^2}\Big) + \frac{2\ln t \ln (1 + \frac{1}{1+t^2})}{\ln 2} > 0.$$

We will use the following bounds (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY41S.jpg)):
\begin{align}
\ln (1 + x) &\ge \frac{x(6+5x)}{2(1+x)(3+x)}, \quad \forall x\in (-1, 0],\tag{1}\\
\ln (1+x) &\ge \frac{2x}{2+x}, \quad \forall x\ge 0.\tag{2}
\end{align}

Applying (1) for $\ln (1-\frac{1}{t^2})$ and (2) for $\ln(1+\frac{1}{1+t^2})$,
it suffices to prove that for all $t \ge \mathrm{e}^{3/5}$,
$$\ln t - \frac{(6t^2-5)(2t^2+3)\ln 2}{8(t^2-1)(3t^2-1)} > 0.$$
Let $f(t) = \ln t - \frac{(6t^2-5)(2t^2+3)\ln 2}{8(t^2-1)(3t^2-1)}.$
We have 
$$f'(t) = \frac{18t^8 - (48 - 36\ln 2)t^6+(44 - 57\ln 2)t^4+(26\ln 2 - 16)t^2+2}{2t(3t^2-1)^2(t^2-1)^2}.$$
Let us prove that $f'(t) > 0$ for $t > 1$.
It suffices to prove that for $t > 1$, 
$$g(t) = 18t^8 - (48 - 36\ln 2)t^6+(44 - 57\ln 2)t^4+(26\ln 2 - 16)t^2+2 > 0.$$
Let $t = 1 + u$ for $u > 0$. We have
\begin{align}
g(1+u) &= 18 u^8+144 u^7+(36 \ln 2+456) u^6+(216 \ln 2+720) u^5\\
&\quad +(483 \ln 2+584) u^4 +(492 \ln 2+224) u^3\\
&\quad +(224 \ln 2+32) u^2+ (40 \ln 2) u + 5 \ln 2.
\end{align}
Clearly, $g(1+u) > 0$. The desired result follows.

Thus, we have $f(t) \ge f(\mathrm{e}^{3/5}) \approx 0.000516 > 0$ for all $t \ge \mathrm{e}^{3/5}$.
We are done.

Similarly, we may prove that for $a > 0$, the inequality holds for $x \ge x_0$ where $x_0$ depends on $a$.

---

EDIT by Andreas: This doesn't change RiverLi's answer above, but expands it for arbitrary $a > 0$. Going along the same paths as above, we obtain

$$
f(t) = \ln t - \frac{a (6t^2-5)(2t^2+1+e^{2a})}{4(t^2-1)(3t^2-1)(e^{2a}-1)} > 0.
$$
The special case above for $a = \frac12 \ln (2)$ obviously follows. Now one can again examine $f'(t= 1+u)$ and obtains the necessary and sufficient condition for the numerator,
\begin{align}
g(1+u) &= 
(18 \exp(2 a) - 18) u^8   \\
&\quad+ (144 \exp(2 a) - 144) u^7  \\
&\quad+ (36 a + 456 \exp(2 a) + 18 a \exp(2 a) - 456)u^6  \\
&\quad+ (216 a + 720 \exp(2 a) + 108 a \exp(2 a) - 720) u^5 \\
&\quad + (486 a + 584 \exp(2 a) + 240 a \exp(2 a)
 - 584) u^4   \\
&\quad+ (504 a + 224 \exp(2 a) + 240 a \exp(2 a)
 - 224)u^3 \\
&\quad+ (240 a + 32 \exp(2 a) + 104 a \exp(2 a) - 32) u^2   \\
&\quad+ (48 a + 16 a \exp(2 a)) u \\
&\quad+ 6 a + 2 a \exp(2 a)
\end{align}
Since $\exp(2a)>1$, this is positive for all $u>0$. This means that the inequality holds at least for all $t>t_0(a)$ which satisfy $f(t_0) = 0$. Note again that this corresponds to $x>\ln (t_0(a))$. Since  $f(t_0) = 0$ can only be solved implicitely, the results are visualized as  follows:
[image]

The special case considered above may be identified in  this figure: $a = \frac12 \ln 2 \simeq 0.347$, $t_0 < e^{3/5} \simeq 1.822$. The limiting cases are $t_0(a=0) \simeq 2.0355$, or $x_0(a=0) \simeq 0.71$, and since for large $t$, $f(t) \simeq \ln t -  a/(\exp(2a) - 1)  - \frac{1}{t^2}\frac{a(\exp(2a)/2 + 1)}{\exp(2a) - 1}$, we have that for large $a$, $t_0^2(a) \ln (t_0(a)) \simeq \frac{a}{2}$ which gives for large $a$, $t_0(a) <\simeq (\frac{e \; a}{2})^{1/3}$ or  $x_0(a) <\simeq \frac13 \ln (\frac{e \; a}{2})$

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY41S.jpg) Topsøe, "Some bounds for the logarithmic function", https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf

Comment: You write "It is easy to prove that $f'(t) > 0$ for all $t\ge 1$.". While it is true that $f'(t) > 0$ for all $t\ge 1$, a proof should be provided - can you add it?

Comment: @Andreas  I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok this makes it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting by $x=\log(t)$ and take logarithm of both terms, it suffices to prove

$$
\log \left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{2 t}\right)-\frac{2 \log (t) \left(\log \left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)-\log \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t}\right)\right)}{\log(2)}+\log (2) \ge 0
$$
for
$t > t_0$, for some fixed $t_0$.

A Taylor expansion of the LHS gives
$$
\frac{2 \log (t)-\log (2)}{t^2 \log (2)}+\frac{-6 \log (t)-\log (2)}{2 t^4 \log (2)}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^6\right)
$$
This is obviously positive for all $t > t_0$ by choosing $t_0$ large enough.